# Rails aborted with access denied; unknown user IP

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am totally new to ruby on rails, trying to set up a project with connection to mysql.
In mysql i've created databases, granted privileges to user like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb_development.* TO 'rails_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
```

In the **database.yml** file i've configured:

```
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
username: rails_user
password: test
host: localhost
```

I am trying to test the connection with schema dump

```
rails db:schema:dump
```

Bizarrely, the access denied message is giving me a weird localhost IP (172.20.0.1), i'm not sure if this is why its failing, but unsure how to resolve from there?

```
rails aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'172.20.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

Tried setting password like this also, to no avail - I cannot even login using this `rails_user` at all with `access denied` error

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'rails_user'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('test');
```

Comment: did you try to login mysql via command line from bash? `mysql -u rails_user -h localhost -p ` ?

Comment: did you run this query `flush privileges;`

Comment: @PiotrGalas yeh for some reason i can't login at all with this user

Comment: @StephenM tried that, no change. Is it not weird its giving IP 172.. instead of localhost or 127.. ?

Comment: rails seems to connect ok with my `root` user, weird that i can't get another other user to connect but oh well for now

Comment: What's the value for localhost in your hosts file?

Comment: So If you can't This question is more related to mysql, than rails. I recommend you to add also tag `mysql` to question